# Converting floats to n-byte binary integer

Tags: binary, integer

Given the following base 10 decimals
a)3.75
b)0.7
c)89.9

convert a) to integer binary 1 byte,
convert b) to integer binary 2 byte,
convert c) to integer binary 3 byte.

These questions are pretty confusing, but I have a guess as to the solution.

a = 37? With the 5 lost. I assume this is true because 375 couldn't be stored in one byte. Then if you divide by 10 you get 3.7 which brings you back to the original number, without the 5.

b = I have no idea...

c = I have no idea...

I would assume for b and c there would be repeating digits since they are fractions and there is a lot of room for precision since 2 bytes=65536 and 3 bytes=16777216. But I don't really have a guess as to how they would be represented. Maybe for b, there would be repeating 0s and for c, repeating 9s?

I would appreciate someone telling me if I am even on the right track here. If not, what is the question asking me to do? You don't have to give me all the answers, I would just appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the assignment?  "convert a) to integer binary 1 byte" etc.?  Unless there is more to it, integer(3.75) = 3.  Is this based on lectures saying to scale up using  x 10,  x100 etc. to fit as much as many digits as possible or what?

Comment: My teacher mentioned bit shifting, but we covered this material very fast and I didn't catch very much of it. This is the exact wording of the assignment. The rest of the assignment is about IEEE float standard, converting to hex, octal, binary, and a different standard similar to IEEE but not the same.

Comment: I sort of inferred that I was suppose to fit in as many digits, I totally assumed that myself really.

Comment: Based *only on the question text* and no other context, the integers are 3, 0 , 89.  We can't really help if the wording is incomplete or there is context around it to suggest some other answer.  With that text (if correct and no context modifies it) the number of bytes is almost a trick question.